# How can I tell if I have Windows 2012 R2 (vs the 'R1' original release')?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

How can I tell if I have Windows 2012 R2 or just "2012"?  I can't seem to see any signs of "R2" anywhere yet I ordered a (remote) server with this installed and I want to verify I have the correct edition installed before I go any further with the server build.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Drop into a command prompt and issue either of the following commands;

```
systeminfo | findstr OS
```

Or

```
winver
```

You can then use this table to determine the version;

> [Operating System Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx)

Which shows:

```
Operating system            Version number
Windows 8.1                 6.3*
Windows Server 2012 R2      6.3*
Windows 8                   6.2
Windows Server 2012         6.2
Windows 7                   6.1
Windows Server 2008 R2      6.1
Windows Server 2008         6.0
Windows Vista               6.0
Windows Server 2003 R2      5.2
Windows Server 2003         5.2
Windows XP 64-Bit Edition   5.2
Windows XP                  5.1
Windows 2000                5.0
```

Based on your comment, it would appear you're running Windows Server 2012 as opposed to Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: But what should it say for R2? Will it actually say "R2" somewhere or just give a later build number?  I'm just getting Version 6.2 (Build 9200).

Comment: Added some more detail for you, I'd appreciate the tick and an upvote if this has worked for you :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 9):

If you have the GUI installed an instant visual clue will be the absence (Server 2012) or presence (Server 2012 R2) of an actual Start button on the taskbar.

Answer (score 7):

In GUI it's easy to check the version: Control Panel > System and Security > System

[image]

Comment: The critical thing was, I wasn't sure if "R2" would say anything different on this screen and "R1" obviously doesn't say R1, so thanks for the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You could also search for the **Software Identification Tag** File (ISO 19772). This is an XML file on your drive. Just search for: regid.1991-06.com.microsoft.*.swidtag

Usually for Windows OS the files are located in "c:\ProgramData\regid.1991-06.com.microsoft". In this file you will find the tag <product_title> e.g.

<product_title>**Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter**</product_title>